# How to find a value in a cell and delete it?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to find a value in a range and then delete that value.

I have found some code, which looks for the value, but then deletes the other cells, not the found value.

This is the code:

```
Private Sub CLEAROLD_Click()

'PURPOSE: Clear out all cells that do not contain a specific word/phrase

Dim Rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim ContainWord As String

'What range do you want to search?
Set Rng = Range("AA2:AC25")

'sub for the word
shorttext = traintype1.Value & number1.Value

'What phrase do you want to test for?
ContainWord = shorttext 

'Loop through each cell in range and test cell contents
For Each cell In Rng.Cells    
    If cell.Find(ContainWord) Is Nothing Then cell.ClearContents  
Next cell

End Sub
```

I tried to change the `if` condition, but I can't make it to work.

Comment: what change did you make? (the change that did not work)

Comment: There is no need to use only capitals in the question's title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using a `For Each cell In Rng.Cells` to loop through your Range's cells, you can compare the cell's values directly with `ContainWord`.

Replace:

```
If cell.Find(ContainWord) Is Nothing Then cell.ClearContents
```

With:

```
If cell.Value2 = ContainWord Then cell.ClearContents
```

Comment: THX it is work now. so the problem was that I did not use new value space  for the (if) right

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be faster to use the replace functionality

```
 rng.Replace What:=shorttext, Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlWhole, _
               SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
               ReplaceFormat:=False
```